# At present, I encounter a problem of converting large HTML files to pdf

Tags: itext

At present, I encounter a problem of converting large HTML files to pdf. It takes more than 10 seconds to convert them. Can I optimize the performance?
This is my code.

```
public static void htmlToPDF(String htmlUrl, String destUrl, String fontUrl) {
        OutputStream os = null;
        try {
            String url;
            url = new File(htmlUrl).toURI().toURL().toString();
            os = new FileOutputStream(destUrl);
            ITextRenderer renderer = new ITextRenderer();
            renderer.setDocument(url);
            ITextFontResolver fontResolver = renderer.getFontResolver();
            fontResolver.addFont(fontUrl, BaseFont.IDENTITY_H, BaseFont.NOT_EMBEDDED);
            renderer.layout();
            renderer.createPDF(os); 
            renderer.finishPDF();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            try {
                os.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
```

I find that layout takes a lot of time. Is there a good way to optimize this?

Comment: Please specify what are the method you're using for the compression or what software is it. Your question is too short for any of us to trying figure out your problems.

Comment: The question has been revised and I look forward to your reply.